# SQL - SELECTING multiple columns with duplicate information and some with unique

Tags: sql, select, db2

I need to produce a query that will pull all the records with:

- Same First_Name
- Same Last_Name
- Same DOB
- Same client_ID (Client_ID is given "1011")
- Different Member_ID

Note: I have huge database with multimillion records, and as soon as I provide more than one subquery it takes hours to provide even first sample of data. (maybe my subqueries were incorrect though)
I've tried building this query step-by-step, but still it fails to filter the way I need.

```
Select
ta.Member_ID,
ta.First_Name,
ta.LAST_NAME,
ta.date_of_birth,
ta.client_id,

From TestTable ta
WHERE client_id = '1011'
AND
        ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM TestTable ta2
                     WHERE ta.date_of_birth=ta2.date_of_birth
                     AND ta.FIRST_NAME=ta2.FIRST_NAME
                     AND ta.LAST_NAME=ta2.LAST_NAME)>1
```

I'm not even got to the point of selecting different Member_ID, and still this query pulls records that not necesary follow those parameters.
Please help.
Here is sample data, highlighted is the pair that I want to be able to get:
[My Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xefs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT ta.Member_ID, ta.First_Name, ta.LAST_NAME, ta.date_of_birth,
       ta.client_id
FROM (SELECT ta.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, date_of_birth) as cnt
      FROM TestTable ta
     ) ta
WHERE client_id = '1011' AND cnt > 1;
```

Comment: It did return all the records with same FName, LName & DOB (took couple hours to pull just a little more than a million records). Now  how do I add one more condition to it? I need same FName, LName & DOB but **Different** "Member_ID"? Thanks a lot, great help

Comment: I have no idea what "different Member_Id" is supposed to mean.  You can pull all the columns in the outer query, though.

Answer (score 0):

As a general note,don't use correlated sub queries unless you absolutely have to. Performance takes a severe hit as the subquery is run for every row of the outer query. A simple join should work:

```
Select
ta.Member_ID,
ta.First_Name,
ta.LAST_NAME,
ta.date_of_birth,
ta.client_id

From TestTable ta JOIN TestTable ta2
WHERE ta.client_id = '1011' AND ta.Member_ID <> ta2.Member_ID
ON ta.date_of_birth=ta2.date_of_birth
                     AND ta.FIRST_NAME=ta2.FIRST_NAME
                     AND ta.LAST_NAME=ta2.LAST_NAME
                     AND ta.client_id=ta2.client_id
```

Comment: This query does not return only the records with same FName, LName and DOB. Also does not really differentiate by MemberID, Result is very similar to what I've wrote but much quicker - works fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your only intention is to find records with same details but diff Member ID use the basic group by to filter data. This is not as costly as joining two tables

```
Select
ta.First_Name,
ta.LAST_NAME,
ta.date_of_birth,
ta.client_id
From TestTable ta
group by 
ta.First_Name,
ta.LAST_NAME,
ta.date_of_birth,
ta.client_id
having count(distinct Member_ID) > 1
```

Comment: IT generates an Error:  An expression starting with "Member_ID" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.

Comment: you have forget ta alias for table, i have corrected ;)